# Windows 10 Disable Search Functionality inside App

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-10, windows-8.1, winjs

I am developing a Windows 8/8.1/10 application in WinJS. Once the app deploys, if you press the three-bar icon at the top left, there is a search option. Upon entering a query, and hitting search, the app crashes.

That's because I haven't provided a search functionality, and it doesn't make sense for my app. How could I disable the search option, and prevent the user from seeing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search option will be listed there if you have registered the app as a search provider in the manifest file.

1. Open `package.appxmanifest` file
2. In the declarations tab, remove search from the supported declarations.

You need to add the declaration only if your app supports search. In that case the below event will fire when the search query is submitted.

```
        protected override void OnWindowCreated(WindowCreatedEventArgs args)
        {
            SearchPane.GetForCurrentView().QuerySubmitted += new TypedEventHandler<SearchPane, SearchPaneQuerySubmittedEventArgs>(OnQuerySubmitted);
            base.OnWindowCreated(args);
        }

        private void OnQuerySubmitted(SearchPane sender, SearchPaneQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
        {

        }
```